# elasticsearch cluster update API does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch version is 2.1.1 .

I just want to update `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` as described in [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) by running this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "transient" : {"discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" : "2"}
}'
```

the response is `{"acknowledged":true,"persistent":{},"transient":{}}` which means there is nothing updated (although it is acknowledged). the response should be something like this:

```
{
    "persistent" : {},
    "transient" : {"discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" : "2"}
}
```

Comment: `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "transient" : {
        "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" : 2
    }
}'`, this is what you are looking for I guess

Comment: I just mistyped it. edited.